# How to get recent data by date from a List<Map<String, String>>?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, localdatetime

Map List have ID, Device Name, New PIN and Created Date.

[image]

Now using below method, I am getting all record present against Moto device

```
mpinRecordList.removeIf(map -> !map.containsValue("Moto"));
```

but how to get the record by recent date.

Comment: System.out.println( mpinRecordList.stream().map(a -> LocalDateTime.parse(a.get("Created_Date"), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"))).max(LocalDateTime::compareTo));
With this I am able to get the result, but it is printing only Created Date, how can get other details ID, Device Name and New PIN

Comment: The same way? Since the values you stored in your Map are of type String you dont need to parse a LocalDateTime.

Comment: @magicmn, Thanks for the correction. Parse is not needed. 
System.out.println(mpinRecordList.stream().map(a -> a.get("Created_Date")).max(String::compareTo));
This prints Optional[15-10-2022 03:16:11.109], but how to print other details for same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Java 8**

You can use the below approach to get the sorted data as required.

***Approach Here:***

- I have filter the list based on `"Moto"` device name as required and then use `sorted()` using `Compartor.comparing()` in which you can pass the attribute by which you want to sort the list, here i have passed the date and after that i have used `.reversed()` in order to get the latest data first.

**Code:**

**Device.java**

```
public class Device {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private long pin;
    private Date date;

    public Device(int id, String name, long pin, Date date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.pin = pin;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getPin() {
        return pin;
    }

    public void setPin(long pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Device{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", pin=" + pin +
                ", date=" + date +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");
        Device d1 = new Device(1,"Samsung",934195,format.parse("15-10-2022 02:18:53.909"));
        Device d2 = new Device(4,"Moto",129876,format.parse("15-10-2022 02:40:11.149"));
        Device d3 = new Device(5,"Moto",671598,format.parse("15-10-2022 02:55:01.879"));
        Device d4 = new Device(6,"Moto",305483,format.parse("15-10-2022 03:15:01.879"));
        Device d5 = new Device(7,"Moto",190352,format.parse("15-10-2022 03:16:11.109"));
        Device d6 = new Device(8,"Sony",278160,format.parse("15-10-2022 03:30:12.809"));

        List<Device> sortedListOfMotoDevice = Arrays.asList(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6).stream().filter(x -> x.getName().equals("Moto"))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Device::getDate).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(sortedListOfMotoDevice);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Device{id=7, name='Moto', pin=190352, date=Sat Oct 15 03:16:11 IST 2022}, Device{id=6, name='Moto', pin=305483, date=Sat Oct 15 03:15:01 IST 2022}, Device{id=5, name='Moto', pin=671598, date=Sat Oct 15 02:55:01 IST 2022}, Device{id=4, name='Moto', pin=129876, date=Sat Oct 15 02:40:11 IST 2022}]
```